# Having trouble using perlbrew to install perl 5.14.2 on OSX 10.8.0

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, perlbrew

On the advice I've read here and elsewhere, I decided to stop running **sudo cpan**, thus affecting the system perl, and instead use perlbrew to install and manage private versions of perl.

I installed **perlbrew** and ran **perlbrew install perl-5.14.2**, both without and with **--force**.  Both times it failed to install.  Below is the test summary report.

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
../ext/POSIX/t/posix.t                            (Wstat: 0 Tests: 66 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   11
../lib/locale.t                                   (Wstat: 0 Tests: 117 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  99
Files=2089, Tests=455813, 723 wallclock secs (55.63 usr  8.56 sys + 402.42 cusr 50.30 csys = 516.91 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

Has anyone had success using perlbrew to install Perl on OSX 10.8, who can suggest what's going wrong?

[UPDATE]

I tried installing perl 5.12.4, and got the same results.  Below are some details that seem to pertain to locale:

```
 The following locales
#
#   C C POSIX POSIX af_ZA af_ZA.ISO8859-1 af_ZA.ISO8859-15
#   af_ZA.UTF-8 am_ET am_ET.UTF-8 be_BY be_BY.CP1131 be_BY.CP1251
#   be_BY.ISO8859-5 be_BY.UTF-8 bg_BG bg_BG.CP1251 bg_BG.UTF-8
#   ca_ES ca_ES.ISO8859-1 ca_ES.ISO8859-15 ca_ES.UTF-8 cs_CZ
#   cs_CZ.ISO8859-2 cs_CZ.UTF-8 da_DK da_DK.ISO8859-1 da_DK.ISO8859-15
#   da_DK.UTF-8 de_AT de_AT.ISO8859-1 de_AT.ISO8859-15
#   de_AT.UTF-8 de_CH de_CH.ISO8859-1 de_CH.ISO8859-15
#   de_CH.UTF-8 de_DE de_DE.ISO8859-1 de_DE.ISO8859-15
#   de_DE.UTF-8 el_GR el_GR.ISO8859-7 el_GR.UTF-8 en_AU
#   en_AU.ISO8859-1 en_AU.ISO8859-15 en_AU.US-ASCII en_AU.UTF-8
#   en_CA en_CA.ISO8859-1 en_CA.ISO8859-15 en_CA.US-ASCII
#   en_CA.UTF-8 en_GB en_GB.ISO8859-1 en_GB.ISO8859-15
#   en_GB.US-ASCII en_GB.UTF-8 en_IE en_IE.UTF-8 en_NZ
#   en_NZ.ISO8859-1 en_NZ.ISO8859-15 en_NZ.US-ASCII en_NZ.UTF-8
#   en_US en_US.ISO8859-1 en_US.ISO8859-15 en_US.US-ASCII
#   en_US.UTF-8 es_ES es_ES.ISO8859-1 es_ES.ISO8859-15
#   es_ES.UTF-8 et_EE et_EE.ISO8859-15 et_EE.UTF-8 eu_ES
#   eu_ES.ISO8859-1 eu_ES.ISO8859-15 eu_ES.UTF-8 fi_FI
#   fi_FI.ISO8859-1 fi_FI.ISO8859-15 fi_FI.UTF-8 fr_BE
#   fr_BE.ISO8859-1 fr_BE.ISO8859-15 fr_BE.UTF-8 fr_CA
#   fr_CA.ISO8859-1 fr_CA.ISO8859-15 fr_CA.UTF-8 fr_CH
#   fr_CH.ISO8859-1 fr_CH.ISO8859-15 fr_CH.UTF-8 fr_FR
#   fr_FR.ISO8859-1 fr_FR.ISO8859-15 fr_FR.UTF-8 he_IL
#   he_IL.UTF-8 hi_IN.ISCII-DEV hr_HR hr_HR.ISO8859-2 hr_HR.UTF-8
#   hu_HU hu_HU.ISO8859-2 hu_HU.UTF-8 hy_AM hy_AM.ARMSCII-8
#   hy_AM.UTF-8 is_IS is_IS.ISO8859-1 is_IS.ISO8859-15
#   is_IS.UTF-8 it_CH it_CH.ISO8859-1 it_CH.ISO8859-15
#   it_CH.UTF-8 it_IT it_IT.ISO8859-1 it_IT.ISO8859-15
#   it_IT.UTF-8 ja_JP ja_JP.SJIS ja_JP.UTF-8 ja_JP.eucJP kk_KZ
#   kk_KZ.PT154 kk_KZ.UTF-8 ko_KR ko_KR.CP949 ko_KR.UTF-8
#   ko_KR.eucKR lt_LT lt_LT.ISO8859-13 lt_LT.ISO8859-4
#   lt_LT.UTF-8 nl_BE nl_BE.ISO8859-1 nl_BE.ISO8859-15
#   nl_BE.UTF-8 nl_NL nl_NL.ISO8859-1 nl_NL.ISO8859-15
#   nl_NL.UTF-8 no_NO no_NO.ISO8859-1 no_NO.ISO8859-15
#   no_NO.UTF-8 pl_PL pl_PL.ISO8859-2 pl_PL.UTF-8 pt_BR
#   pt_BR.ISO8859-1 pt_BR.UTF-8 pt_PT pt_PT.ISO8859-1 pt_PT.ISO8859-15
#   pt_PT.UTF-8 ro_RO ro_RO.ISO8859-2 ro_RO.UTF-8 ru_RU
#   ru_RU.CP1251 ru_RU.CP866 ru_RU.ISO8859-5 ru_RU.KOI8-R
#   ru_RU.UTF-8 sk_SK sk_SK.ISO8859-2 sk_SK.UTF-8 sl_SI
#   sl_SI.ISO8859-2 sl_SI.UTF-8 sr_YU sr_YU.ISO8859-2 sr_YU.ISO8859-5
#   sr_YU.UTF-8 sv_SE sv_SE.ISO8859-1 sv_SE.ISO8859-15
#   sv_SE.UTF-8 tr_TR tr_TR.ISO8859-9 tr_TR.UTF-8 uk_UA
#   uk_UA.ISO8859-5 uk_UA.KOI8-U uk_UA.UTF-8 zh_CN zh_CN.GB18030
#   zh_CN.GB2312 zh_CN.GBK zh_CN.UTF-8 zh_CN.eucCN zh_HK
#   zh_HK.Big5HKSCS zh_HK.UTF-8 zh_TW zh_TW.Big5 zh_TW.UTF-8
#
# tested okay.
#
# None of your locales were broken.
../lib/locale.t ................................................... 
Failed 1/117 subtests
```

So none were "broken", but one "failed".  And that, it seems, prevents the installation from succeeding, even by force.

Comment: Nice rendering there.  It basically ends by saying none were broken, and one failed.

Comment: I was getting this test failure along with a couple others trying to install 5.10.1 on yosemite. Taking the hint from the error message, `cd`ing into the downloaded directory and manually `make install` worked for me, even with existing test failures.

Answer (score 5):

The fault comes from test 99 of the "be_BY.CP1131" locale.

The ultimate fix needs to come from either the Perl developers or Apple.

In the mean time, you can get the install to work by moving /usr/share/locale/be_BY.CP1131 to some other directory. Perl will no longer test this locale. This isn't an ideal solution, but it will get you perlbrew perl assuming you don't need this specific locale.

Comment: Nailed it. I was having the same problem installing Perl 5.8.9 with perlbrew and your workaround fixed it. I saw that locale.t avoids testing the locale for eu_ES under OS X, perhaps the same fix could be added to Perl, instead of removing a locale from OS X.

Comment: Has anyone reported this issue to Apple, or have any details regarding what's wrong with the locale?  It's been a problem for quite some time, and still outstanding in OS 10.10.2.

Comment: OS X 12.3, perl 5.14.4 same problem exists!