# Installing Perl 5.10.1 on Yosemite with perlbrew fails groups.t test

Tags: perl, osx-yosemite, perlbrew

perlbrew version is 0.7.3, OS X version is 10.10.2. After working around an [issue with locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917050/having-trouble-using-perlbrew-to-install-perl-5-14-2-on-osx-10-8-0), I'm stuck on an issue with groups.t:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
op/groups.t                                                    (Wstat: 0 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  1
../ext/POSIX/t/posix.t                                         (Wstat: 0 Tests: 66 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   11
Files=1711, Tests=227048, 393 wallclock secs (15.98 usr  5.88 sys + 159.41 cusr 22.97 csys = 204.24 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1711 test programs. 1/227048 subtests failed.
make[2]: *** [_test_tty] Error 255
make[1]: *** [_test] Error 2
make: *** [test_harness] Error 2
```

Not being a Perl expert, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**:

I've ran the test manually, and got this output:

```
Vladimirs-MacBook-Pro:perl-5.10.1 bermanlab$ ./perl t/op/groups.t 
# groups = uid=504(bermanlab) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.4),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),70(_www),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),401(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
# groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.4),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),70(_www),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),401(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3),402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
# g0 = 20(staff) 701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.4) 12(everyone) 61(localaccounts) 70(_www) 79(_appserverusr) 80(admin) 81(_appserveradm) 98(_lpadmin) 401(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1) 33(_appstore) 100(_lpoperator) 204(_developer) 398(com.apple.access_screensharing) 399(com.apple.access_ssh) 403(com.apple.sharepoint.group.3) 402(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2)
# g1 = staff com.apple.sharepoint.group.4 everyone localaccounts _www _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 _appstore _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh com.apple.sharepoint.group.3 com.apple.sharepoint.group.2
1..2
# pwgid = 20, pwgnam = staff
# gr = com.apple.sharepoint.group.4 everyone localaccounts _www _appserverusr admin _appserveradm _lpadmin com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 _appstore _lpoperator _developer com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh com.apple.sharepoint.group.3
#gr1 is <_appserveradm _appserverusr _appstore _developer _lpadmin _lpoperator _www admin com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 com.apple.sharepoint.group.3 com.apple.sharepoint.group.4 everyone localaccounts>
#gr2 is <_appserveradm _appserverusr _appstore _developer _lpadmin _lpoperator _www admin com.apple.access_screensharing com.apple.access_ssh com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 com.apple.sharepoint.group.2 com.apple.sharepoint.group.3 com.apple.sharepoint.group.4 everyone localaccounts>
not ok 1
ok 2
```

Comment: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=71508, https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=116775

Comment: @choroba, they're still open. I'll file a bug report and reference them.

Comment: Yes, they seem to need a heads up.